# Get intermediate result from thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a thread in which I do heavy calculations. In the overlying thread I cyclic check for new results. The code below shows how I check the current best result.

```
private class BestFitThreadClass
{
    public double bestError { get; private set; }

    public void calculate()
    {
        //do some heavy calculation
        for (i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
            bestError = i;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var myBestFit = new BestFitThreadClass();

    var myBestFitThread = new Thread(myBestFit.calculate);
    myBestFitThread.Start();

    double oldError = double.MaxValue;

    while(myBestFitThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
    {
        if (myBestFit.bestError < oldError)
        {
            oldError = myBestFit.bestError;
            Console.WriteLine(oldError);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Doing it this way I miss many intermediate results.
Is there a way to trigger an event in the overlying thread each time a new bestError is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Progress` instance to allow an operation to indicate the progress of that operation to external entities, based on the progress of that operation.  The caller can specify an action to perform when there are progress updates (in this case, writing the progress out to the console) and then the operation itself can report progress to the object when it computes each intermediate value.